# Error 'Column count of mysql.user is wrong' on MySQL SLAVE

Tags: mysql, passwords, replication

I changed replication user password on master, logged into slave, stop slave and did change master to password to newly changed password and started slave, now slave is showing following error:

```
 Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 43, found 39. The table is probably corrupted' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'SET PASSWORD FOR 'repl'@'iip.ip.ip.ip'='*JSHHASHHSAHSHAHSAHSHASHASH''
```

Master is on: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73,
Slave is on: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.51

Can anyone help me how to resolve this? SLAVE already on high version, I just need errors gone.

Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like in the slave rebuilding process you have restored mysql database dump from master in 5.1 version to slave at 5.6. Which means you have corrupted the mysql system database in slave. Try running mysql_upgrade mostly it should fix inplace upgrades and all. Else you have to rebuild this slave and this time restore dump without mysql database and create users on slave directly instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! mysql_upgrade resolved the issue.